# How to create new column calculating of date in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have DataFrame like below:

```
df['Date'] =
...
936   2012-12-31
938   2012-12-29
965   2012-12-31
966   2012-12-31
967   2012-12-31
968   2012-12-31
969   2012-12-31
970   2012-12-29
971   2012-12-31
972   2012-12-29
973   2012-12-29
```

And I need to create 1 new column in this DataFrame:

1. New1 = amount of months from "Date" column until today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the most elegant way, but it works here it is

```py
data = { 'Date': [np.datetime64('2012-12-31'), np.datetime64('2012-12-29'), np.datetime64('2012-12-31')]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date'])

def calculate_months(date):
    now = datetime.datetime.now() 
    diff = now - date 
    return diff / np.timedelta64(1,'M')

df['New1'] = df.Date.apply(calculate_months).tolist()
```

Everything tricky is inside calculate_months, basically find the delta between now and the time passed as an argument and then translate that to months, if you don't need the decimal part, you can just floor it or something like that.

Comment: I have an error: NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined

Comment: I omitted the imports, you have to import NumPy and datetime in order for this code to work, so just add `import numpy as np` and `import datetime`